# Counting the number of elements in a list and then taking the counting as a list in R

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
x <- c(0.8,1.0,661.7,661.8,661.9,662.3,662.6,662.7,663.3,663.6,663.7)
```

I have used function `as.data.frame(x)` to make following data frame:

```
       X1
1      0.8
2      1.0
3    661.7
4    661.8
5    661.9
6    662.3
7    662.6
8    662.7
9    663.3
10   663.6
11   663.7
```

How can I take the list of labels for each element?

i.e `x0 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)`

Comment: When I tried this it threw an error "object 'x0' not found, is there a way to somehow extract this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can have a named `vector` and use `stack` and this is also flexible in having different labels

```
stack(setNames(x, seq_along(x)))
```

---

Or using `rownames_to_column`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(x) %>%
     rownames_to_column('rn')
```

Comment: I tried this as well, I think it works for the purpose I need it for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you already created that dataframe, take out the rownames:

```
x <- c(0.8,1.0,661.7,661.8,661.9,662.3,662.6,662.7,663.3,663.6,663.7)
rownames(as.data.frame(x))
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11"
```